# Image goes beyond container div bounds

Tags: html, css

Can someone take a look at the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R4bCy/1/

I thought that a div should adjust it's height in order to accommodate it's elements, unless the elements are positioned absolutely.

Why does the div not expand to the full height of the image?

I need to the image to be aligned to the right. The only ways that I know how to do this is `align='right'`, `position:absolute; right: 0;` and `float:right`, all of which make the containing div not adjust it's height to the image height.

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me...

Comment: The red container fully contains the text and image for you?

Comment: The red container fully contains the text and image for me on Chrome...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
.intro {
margin: 10px;
outline: 1px solid #CCC;
background: #A00;
color: #FFF;
height:auto;
overflow:auto;
}
​.img{
float:right;
height:auto;
}​

<div class="intro">
    <div class="img"> <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_74so2YIdYpM/TEd09Hqrm6I/AAAAAAAAApY/rwGCm5_Tawg/s1600/tall+copy.jpg"    style="margin: 10px 10px; "/></div>

  <p>Sorry, but the page you requested could not be found.</p>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/R4bCy/7/)

Comment: This worked for my problem, too.  This should be the go to answer.

Answer (score 13):

> 'Why does the div not expand to the full height of the image?'

Because floats will overlap with blocks, only block formatting contexts contain floats. (You can find a pretty good overview of the whole topic here: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/05/19/css-101-block-formatting-contexts/ )

On to solve the problem at hand:

The `align=right` will actually result in the img being `float: right` (the `align` attribute is deprecated and css should be used).

To contain the floated image in its parent `div` you need either have the parent `div` establish a block formatting context (block formatting contexts enclose nested floats) or explicitly clear the float with an additional element after the `img` that is styled as a `clear: right`.

An easy solution to create a block formatting context is to float the parent `div` as well, although my preferred solution in this case would be to simply set its `overflow` to `hidden` (also resulting in a block formatting context).

Check out the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/R4bCy/8/.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is add after the p tag,

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whoops, apologies, posted and you edited your question - the align right is floating it I believe (you should instead use float:right and a [clearfix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) of some sort).

example: http://jsfiddle.net/R4bCy/5/

Comment: How do I keep the image on the right side of the container without floating it?

Comment: No sorry I think I must have updated my question right when you submitted your answer. I will go with the clearfix route. Thanks!

Comment: Haha, I was so confused by that:) Glad it helped!

Comment: Also, I should note, there are may styles of clearing floats - clearfix is arguably not the best solution, you may find overflow auto or another solution is cleaner and works better for you in this case: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Answer (score 1):

This is what I believe you want:
http://jsfiddle.net/R4bCy/6/

If you wanted the text on the left and the image floated to the right, please do this is your CSS: 
http://jsfiddle.net/R4bCy/15/

You can also have two `div`s that have a width of 50% contained within a container `div`. This will allow you a little more flexibility in your placement of the image because the text and image will each have their own modifiable `div`s with independent attributes