# trying to align div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Some text content are smaller and some are bigger how to make them look same and apply same margin

also, when I reduce browser size say mobile size I see gap between second and third div
here is link to codepen http://codepen.io/rahulv/pen/PGLBdY

css:

```
.  div.outer_certi{
margin-top:2%;
height: 100%;
  }
  .certification p{
 padding:1% 1% 1% 1%;
 }
 .certification img{
padding:1% 1% 1% 1%;
float: left;
max-width:200px;
height:auto;
 }
 .certification{
 border:1px solid #e6e6e6;
 background-color:#faf9f;
overflow:hidden;
}
.certification:hover{
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}
```

Comment: try `background-image("your/image/location");`

Comment: Why did you mark this question with "html", "html5", "twitter-bootstrap" and "javascript" if you don't use any of them

Comment: You need to clear the floats just use the class boostrap have http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-clearfix ... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAojgN

Comment: Your `background-color` is missing a character. Hex codes are always 6 characters long, but yours is 5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image goes beyond container div bounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695726/image-goes-beyond-container-div-bounds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `.certification` class add `overflow:hidden;`

the gap comes from your `div.outer_certi` selector. remove margin from that rule.

if you want to add the margin for only the first element, then do this

```
div.outer_certi:first-of-type {
margin-top:2%;
}
```

and if you want all the div to be the same height, you can try :

```
.certification{
 min-height:150px;/* set this to you choice*/
}
```

Comment: Yup it worked.. Thanks but when I reduce browser size I see gap between second and third dive

Comment: remove margin from `div.outer_certi`

Comment: I need that because I dont want it to start from begining of page

Comment: see updated question on how to make all div look similar because I have less text in some div

Comment: what do you expect the less text divs to do ?

Comment: I think they all should look similar size so both the col-6 in on row should be of same height

Comment: try with `min-height: your choice of value;`. see answer edits

Answer (score 1):

The overflow property specifies what happens if content overflows an element's box. By default this property is set to visible. The overflow is not clipped. It renders outside the element's box. This is what you are seeing now.

Changing the overflow property to 'hidden' results in the overflow being clipped, and the rest of the content will be invisible.

In your case:

```
.certification {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: .certification {
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 150px;
}